# How to access the app instance of flask in other modules

Tags: python-3.x, flask

**RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.**

on using current_app in different modules in flask

I am using Flask and trying to do the following.

I have my app.py which looks like this:

```python
from flask import Flask
from utils import message

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["APP_NAME"] = "my_app"

@app.route('/')
def index():
 name = message()
 return {"message": f"My app is {name}"}
```

I have my utils.py which looks like this:

```python
from flask import current_app
name = current_app.config["APP_NAME"]

def message():
 return name
```

when i am accessing the current_app it is proviing me the following error:

**RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.**

I dont know why it is occuring, and how can it be avoided so that i can have the app instance as global to be used in various other modules.

Thanks,
Akshat